# Print line above specific string from txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have txt file contains data, i want to loop over file and print only line above "City" word.

Ex of txt file:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
PACKAGES
Test TOURS
City
UK
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
PACKAGES
```

Result Expected:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
Test TOURS
```

I tried:

```
with open('dd.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    input_file = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        if 'City' in line:
            f1 = (input_file[:i])
            f2 = str(f1)
            f3 = (f2.replace("['", ''))
            f4 = (f3.replace("\\n']", ''))
            print(f4)
```

Result:

```
NEW FUSTAT TOURS
NEW FUSTAT TOURS\n', 'City\n', 'USA\n', 'Addres\n', 'napolean\n', 'Phone Number\n', '************\n', 'Email\n', '***************\n', 'PACKAGES\n', 'Test TOURS
```

Any kind of help please?

Comment: Your code seems to involve details (e.g. [ and ]) which are lacking from your problem description. What is the point of those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('dd.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    line = ''
    for next_line in f:
        if next_line.startswith('City'):
            print(line)
        line = next_line.strip()
```

EDIT:

```
with open('dd.txt') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    line = ''
    for next_line in f:
        if next_line.startswith('City'):
            f_out.write(line)
        line = next_line
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use regex to find out what you need. As an example:

```
import re
your_match = re.search(r'(.+\R)City', your_text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy achieved by using regular expressions
So you want to find all lines that have `City` line right after them. So regex will be

```
".+\nCity"
```

And a code to find all matched (supposing text is placed in `input.txt`) is

```
import re

with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

for matched in re.findall(".+\nCity", text):
    print(matched[:-5])
```

##### P.S.

You are striping `\nCity` part in matched[:-5] slice

Answer (score 2):

With the line `f1 = (input_file[:i])` you get a list of the entire file up to the line in which you find the string "City". If you replace your for-loop with the following, you're done. I'll explain below what the trick is.

```py
for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
    if 'City' in line:
        f1 = input_file[i-1]
        print(f1.strip())
```

What you do in the line with `f1` is that you get the "row" previous to the one you find the string "City". In the line thereafter, we print the line with any whitespace "stripped".

Answer (score 2):

While iterating the file line-wise, keep track of the line before the current one:

```
with open("h.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""NEW FUSTAT TOURS
City
USA
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
PACKAGES
Test TOURS
City
UK
Addres
napolean
Phone Number
************
Email
***************
PACKAGES""")

last_line = None
r = []
with open("h.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "City" and last_line:
            r.append(last_line)
        else:
            last_line = line.strip()

print(r)
```

Output:

```
['NEW FUSTAT TOURS', 'Test TOURS']
```

Answer (score 0):

These are a lot of for loops, but they work:

```
lines = []
with open('word.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        lines.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    file.close()
indices = []
for line in lines:
    if line == 'City':
        indices.append(lines.index(line) - 1)
        lines[lines.index(line)] = 'FOUND'

for index in indices:
    print(lines[index])
```